# Which spell checker does gedit use?

Tags: linux, spell-checking, gedit

People claim different things(such as aspell, enchant, etc.) on different web pages.

However, as far as I can see, it uses hunspell.

Does anyone have solid knowledge on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a gedit developper on the gedit mailing list:

> We don't use aspell directly, but use 'enchant' which is a kind of frontend for multiple spell checker dictionaries.

See the discussion online: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2010-April/msg00023.html

Comment: Thank you. When I was trying to clear the point that confused me at the very beginning, I realized that "enchant" directly uses "hunspell" instead of "myspell" even though in the configuration file only myspell is specified.

Answer (score 4):

Without aspell being installed there was not even a "language set" dictionary available to me!   In fact, none of the auto spell check was working for the Gnome interface desktop.  However, by a simple and quick installation of aspell then everything was working on my laptop.  My desktop had always been working for all this so I thought I just had something wrong with my laptop installation.  I have Ubuntu 10.10 running on both.

This is a very easy and quick fix if you know about it!   Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually for Greek language the command is.

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-el
```

After I run the command I have the option for Greek Dictionary in gedit.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: apt-get is the package manager for debian-based distributions. Other distributions might have other package managers like yum, pacman, etc.